# How to guarantee std::vector<Vec3> has equivalent memory layout as float[]?

Tags: c++

I want this:

```
GLfloat vertices2[]  {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // left
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // right
        0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // top
};
```

And this:

```
std::vector<Vec3> vertices3 {
        {{ -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f}, // left
         { 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f },// right
         { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f}}  // top
};
```

To have equivalent memory layout so that I can pass it off to OpenGL.

IIUC, `std::vector` is guaranteed to lay its data out contiguously, but I'm not so sure about my `Vec3` class.

I've defined `Vec3` as:

```
class Vec3 {
private:
    GLfloat _data[3];

public:
    Vec3(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z) : _data{x,y,z} {};

    GLfloat &x = _data[0];
    GLfloat &y = _data[1];
    GLfloat &z = _data[2];

    inline GLfloat &operator[](size_t i) {
        return _data[i];
    }
};
```

But I think something is wrong, because `vertices3.data()` doesn't seem to be equivalent to `vertices2`.

---

Oh.. I think my references aren't quite free, are they? `GLfloat &x = _data[0]` is adding a pointer? Is there another way I can write this without incurring a penalty and still keep the `.x`, `.y` syntax in addition to `[]`?

Answer (score 5):

Those `GLFloat&` members take up space as well. Replace them with member functions like:

```
GLfloat& x() { return _data[0]; }
const GLfloat x() const { return _data[0]; }
```

Or simply use `glm::vec3` from the GLM library, which is commonly used.